# Defining Data type in POJO class when a field can be of multiple types

Tags: android, ormlite

I am using ormlite android in my app and i have a table which have a column which can store three type of data which are actually the object of three different class.I want to declare data type of that field in my pojo class and i also tried with Object but still it is showing error.Ormlite does not understand Object data type.

Does ormlite provide any support for such functionality?

**Edit 1**

This is my pojo class

```
@DatabaseTable(tableName = "itinerary_item")
public class ItineraryItem {
@DatabaseField(columnName = "id", id = true)
private int mId;

@DatabaseField(dataType = DataType.SERIALIZABLE, columnName = "item_type", foreign = true, foreignAutoRefresh = true)
private Object mItem;
```

Where this mitem can be of 3 different Type in the database which is basically the object of three different POJO class.
But my problem is that ORMLite is not supporting the Object data type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Please provide a sample of code from the object you are trying to persist and please list the *full* exception that [ORMLite](http://ormlite.com/) is throwing.**

---

But in the meantime I can talk a bit about what types ORMLite can persist.  Here's the full list:

> http://ormlite.com/docs/data-types

It will detect the various fields types.  For objects that are specifically on the list, ORMLite also supports persisting objects that implement `Serializable`.  For these you have to specifically declare the type with `@DatabaseField(dataType = DataType.SERIALIZABLE)`.

> http://ormlite.com/docs/serializable

Lastly, for advanced users, you can define and register your own persister class with the `@DatabaseField(persisterClass = ....class)` code.

---

**Edit:**

I would suggest if `mitem` is one of 3 types then you have 3 separate fields, each with a definitive type -- don't use `Object`.  Then for every instance of your pojo class, 1 of the 3 fields will be set and the others will be null.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I Tried it with SERIALIZABLE but it is giving the following Exception                                      SQL Exception is thrown Field class class java.lang.Object for field FieldType:name=mItem,class=ItineraryItem is not valid for data type SERIALIZABLE

Comment: As the answer and the documentation state, objects persisted as type `SERIALIZABLE` must implement the interface `java.io.Serializable`.  Does `ItineraryItem` do that?

Comment: Another approach that i have used is just set the mItem as String type with three different string for three different class and on object type data field without annotation of the ormlite and on the basis of the string i just initialize that object. Just comment which approach is better? And anyway thanks for your quick help

Comment: That's fine as well but it feels like a C solution, not Java.  Is there some memory limitation that you are trying to get around?  Are you sure that your solution actually results in a smaller footprint?  Because it is certainly heavier from a runtime and code maintenance standpoint.  Best of luck.

Comment: Ya right but the problem with my application is the pojo class should be same at server and client side as hibernate is supporting the object type so we can't do it to make three seperate field but any way and  i think this approach will same some memory.